# MDB onMessage fails with closed JDBC connection

Tags: jdbc, xa, jboss-eap-7, jboss-mdb

Running an app on JBoss eap 7.0.  I have an MDB that also references a XA data source (oracle) to persist data.  After a long time span of no use (several hours),  next onMessage invocation that does to write to DB, gets error below

```
    org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection


    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: 
IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() 
cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@178ff38
2[state=DESTROYED managed 
connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@70289860 connection handles=0 lastReturned=1506796773697 lastValidated=1506796773525 lastCheckedOut=1506947349429 trackByTx=false 
pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@5968abc8 
mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@83405c5[pool=HIF-
BannerPU] 
xaResource=XAResourceWrapperImpl@2168086b[xaResource=org.jboss.jca.adapters.j
dbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@70289860 pad=false overrideRmValue=null 
productName=Oracle productVersion=Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition 
Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production jndiName=java:/jdbc/HIF-BannerPU] 
txSync=null
```

Should I be setting validate-on-match = true, or is there a better approach to ensure pooled connection is valid and active?

UPDATE:  changed config to:

```
                <validation>
                    <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match> 
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.Or‌​acleValidConnectionC‌​hecker"/>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.Or‌​acleExceptionSorter" />
                </validation> 
                <xa-pool>
                    <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
                    <no-tx-separate-pools />
                </xa-pool>
```

Still getting error.

Comment: Yes connection pool validation settings is mandatory for  all the datasources.
~~~
<validation>
<validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
<valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"></valid-connection-checker>
<exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"></exception-sorter>
</validation>
~~~

Comment: Verify the is-same-rm-override and no-tx-separate-pools elements are explicitly declared in each xa-datasource involved per Oracle specific (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/configuration_guide/#example_oracle_xa_datasource)

<xa-pool>
      ...
     <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
      <no-tx-separate-pools />
</xa-pool>

Comment: Your comments fixed the problem.  Please post as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes connection pool validation settings is mandatory for all the data sources:

```
<validation> 

<validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match> <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.Or‌​acleValidConnectionC‌​hecker"></valid-conn‌​ection-checker> 

<exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.Or‌​acleExceptionSorter"‌​></exception-sorter> 

</validation>
```

Also verify the **is-same-rm-override and no-tx-separate-pools** elements are explicitly declared in each xa-datasource involved per Oracle specific (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/configuration_guide/#example_oracle_xa_datasource)

```
<xa-pool> ... 
<is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override> 
<no-tx-separate-pools /> 
</xa-pool>
```